# Why does reverse function changes the original string value in C?

Tags: c, string, reference, reverse

This code is just reversing the string. Here the string is passed by value then how does it reverse the original string since I'm not assigning the function return value to any variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char [], int, int);
int main()
{
char str1[20];
int size;

printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
scanf("%s", str1);
size = strlen(str1);
reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", str1);
return 0;
}

void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size)
{
char temp;
temp = str1[index];
str1[index] = str1[size - index];
str1[size - index] = temp;
if (index == size / 2)
{
    return;
}
reverse(str1, index + 1, size);
}
```

Comment: Maybe the string isn't passed by value after all?

Comment: When you call `reverse(str1, 0, size - 1)` you're passing an address of the original string to the function, not a copy of the string, so the function is changing the original string. In C, the symbol `str1` represents the address of the string/array, so you are passing by value. You're just passing the *value of the address*. That's just the way C syntax works for arrays. There isn't a syntax for passing an array directly by value.

Comment: The string is not being passed at all. That's not how C works. What you're doing is passing a reference to the string (which is being passed by value).

Comment: "Passing a string by value" is meaningless in C--C has no string type. What you pass by value is the memory address of the first byte of the string, and the function is free to stomp all over that memory.

Comment: thanks a lot for clearing my doubt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings and arrays in general are not first-class data types in C; as such you cannot pass a string by value in C, the argument:

```
char str1[]
```

is the same as

```
char* str1
```

Try checking `sizeof(str1)` inside the function for example - you will find that it is the same as `sizeof(char*)` regardless of the size of the string passed.  You could also observe that `printf( "%p\n", str1 );` shows `str1` in `reverse()` refers to the same memory as `str1` in `main()` (or simply observe the same in your debugger).

So you are in fact passing by reference, which is why the caller string is modified.